# How do I change text on the button for npm package react-microsoft-login?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to build a login/register page that will allow multiple users to login/register with multiple login providers such as Microsoft, Google, Instragram etc.

I managed to figure out how to do it with Google and Instagram 3rd party npm packages however, with the Microsoft Login button, there is no option to change the text at all? Is this possible? I want to change it from "Sign in with Microsoft" to "Log in with Microsoft" and "Register with Microsoft" I have my own functionality to handle oAuth registration process.

Here is my code I'll only show the portion that I cannot figure out. In addition, this is the link that shows what props are available for the package.

[Microsoft Login npm package doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-microsoft-login)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import MicrosoftLogin from 'react-microsoft-login';

import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';


import * as actions from 'redux/actions';


const microsoftResponse = (err, response) => {
  console.log('err = ', err);

  console.log('response successful', response);
};


const RegisterPage = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  return (
    <Page title={'Register'}>
      <div className={'loginContainer shadow-lg bg-white rounded'}>
        <div className={'loginWrapper'}>
          <div className={'row'}>
            <div className={'col-md-6'}>
              <div className={'wrapperOverlay px-4'}>
                <h1 className={'text-center'} style={{ borderBottom: '4px solid #ff0000', color: '#ff0000', padding: '20px 0' }}><strong>Register</strong></h1>
                <div className={'providers text-center'}>
                  <ButtonRow id={'loginProvider'}>
                    <MicrosoftLogin
                      clientId={xxxxxxxxx}
                      authCallback={microsoftResponse}
                      redirectUri={xxxxxxxxx}
                    />
                  </ButtonRow>
                </div>

                <div className={'separator py-3'}>Or create a new local account</div>
                <div className={'formContainer'}>
                  <Form
                    enableReinitialize
                    form={'exampleFormName'}
                    onSubmit={(values) => alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2))}
                  >
                    <FieldInput name={'email'} label={'Email'} type={'email'} placeholder={'Email Address'} />
                    <FieldInput name={'password'} label={'Password'} type={'password'} placeholder={'Password'} />
                    <FieldInput name={'confirmpassword'} label={'Confirm Password'} type={'password'} placeholder={'Confirm Password'} />
                    <div className={'resendConfirmation pb-3'}>
                      <Link to={'/resendemailConfirmation'}>Resend email confirmation</Link>
                    </div>

                    <Button className={'w-100 text-center'} type={'submit'} variant={'primary'} text={'Register'} style={{ fontSize: '20px' }} />

                    <div className={'form-group text-right'}>

                      <div className={'registerButton pt-3'}>
                        <span>Already have an Account?</span>
&nbsp;
                        <Link to={'/login'}>
                          <span id={'question'}>Log In</span>
                        </Link>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </Form>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Page>
  );
};

export default RegisterPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change text "as it is", because for a button used SVG image. But as workaround, you can pass your custom button by a children prop, with any text that you want.

```
<MicrosoftLogin clientId={clientId} authCallback={loginHandler}>
  <button>Log in with Microsoft</button>
</MicrosoftLogin>
```

Few things to keep in mind:

- you need to do styling for custom button from scratch
- button styles should be based on [Official Microsoft brand design](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-branding-in-azure-ad-apps)